Differential equation with Zigzag numbers.
I'm given the recurrence relation
$$ 2E_{n+1} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \begin{pmatrix} n \\ j \end{pmatrix} E_j E_{n-j}, \quad n = 1, 2, \dots $$
with $E_0 = 1$ and $E_1 = 1$.
And the function
$$ F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_n}{n!}x^n $$
I am also given the identities
$$ \left( \sum_{n=0} a_n x^n \right) \left( \sum_{n=0} b_n x^n \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{j=0}^n a_j b_{n-j} \right) x^n $$
And
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_nx^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n  $$
I am asked to show
$$
2\frac{dF}{dx} = 1 + F(x)^2
$$
Following is my work
$$
\begin{align*}
F(x) F(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{E_j}{j!} \frac{E_{n-j}}{(n-j)!} \right) x^n \\
&=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^n n! \frac{E_j}{j!} \frac{E_{n-j}}{(n-j)!} \right) x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2E_{n+1}}{n!} x^n \\
\end{align*}
$$
Also
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{dF}{dx} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nE_n}{n!}x^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)E_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{E_{n+1}}{n!} x^n
\end{align*}
$$
This implies
$$
F(x)^2 = 2\frac{dF}{dx}
$$
As is apparent, I'm missing the additive term $1$. I'm not sure where I went wrong or where I'm supposed to get that $1$ from. I presume it might have something to do at the indices at some point in the derivation.

The initial recursion tells us that $2E_1=E_0^2$, though we are not told $E_0$.  The constant term of $F(x)^2$ is clearly $E_0^2$ which matches what you wrote, as that is the same as $2E_1$. The constant term of $F'(x)$ is $E_1$ so your equation balances at least in the constant term.  Adding a $1$ would break that balance.

@lulu There's a latter part to the question that asks to solve the equation that is required to be shown to be satisfied by $F(x)$ in this part. And the solution is well-known as I found searching the internet. And acquiring that solution needs that additive $1$.
I have also added $E_0$ and $E_1$ since you mentioned them.

The initial values $E_0=E_1=1$ are not consistent with the recurrence relation at $n=0$.

@Pranay Aren't those base cases and aren't meant to be found from the recurrence relation? Like we define the first two fibonacci numbers as $1$ and then state the recurrence relation they have?

Then you should say that the recurrence relation is defined only for $n\ge 1$, which isn’t clear from your post.

Since your recurrence relation isn’t valid for $n=0$, you can’t use it for the $n=0$ term in the expansion of $F(x)^2$. That should give you the expected answer.

I think I'm onto something based on what you just said, @Pranay. That was insightful, thank you.
